# Get value from Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to get street from c# dictionary but it is not working(getting some error)

code

```
string data_scope_api = '[
  {

    "retailerName": "vv",
    "name": null,
    "address": {
      "fullShopName": "vv",
      "street": "vv",

    },

  },
  {

    "retailerName": "vv",
    "name": null,
    "address": {
      "fullShopName": "vv",
      "street": "vv"
    },

  }
]'






        dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data_scope_api);
        foreach (var result in results) {

            string address = result.address;
            Console.Write (address);
            foreach (var address_1 in address) {
                string store_street = address_1.street;
                Console.Write (store_street);
            }
        }
```

error

```
Program.cs(37,37): Error CS1061: Type `char' does not contain a definition for `street' and no extension method `street' of type `char' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (test)
```

How to fix and make this program work?

Comment: At least format your question properly. And btw, I don't think `address` is a `string` according to your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the address into a string variable. Use dynamic instead.

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    dynamic address = result.address; // address is dynamic address json
    Console.Write(address);

    string store_street = address.street; // street is string data
    Console.Write(store_street);
}
```